# IE6 is duplicating characters, can't figure out why. Suggestions?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, duplicate-data

Problem is located on http://www.preownedweddingdresses.com/

We have a dresses slider at the bottom, select tabs different dresses shown.

Works fine everywhere else, but for some reason, in IE6, the letters "ls" (from the tab "Best Deals") are duplicating inside the content and causing rendering issues.

I've yet to find anything that can fix this, or anything that can be blamed for causing this either.

I've changed the letters at the end of Best Deals, and the duplicated letters change as well.

Open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've (re-)discovered [another of the many reasons that *every* web developer hates IE6](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/dup-characters.html).